# Why does this user have a low reputation?

Tags: support, specific-question

Why does  [this Stack Overflow user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/339046) only have 20 reputation when the reputation graph shows 280?

---

Reputation graph:

[alt text http://drmortensen.eu/1/until2038-01-19/LowReputation_user339046_2010-05b_16c.png](http://drmortensen.eu/1/until2038-01-19/LowReputation_user339046_2010-05b_16c.png)

Comment: I couldn't find anything to account for it (like any Qs or As deleted as "spam or offensive") so I recalculated his rep.  That seems to have fixed it.

Comment: He did have some other accounts merged recently, which may account for the discrepancy.

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing 325 reps currently.

Comment: Read Bill's comment; his rep was recalculated.

Comment: @Kop: Thanks, that explains it.